# Glass Shader for PNG Export

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am trying to model a tub with clear material. The output will be PNGs as these assets will be used as static images and videos (PNG sequence to Adobe)

My issue is the clear material is not perfect, the thickness of the materials generates dark areas.[image]
[image]

As you can see when exported as PNGs they have dark thick edges/sides.

[image: Shader Editor Screen Shot]

Comment: hello, it's reflecting your World so maybe change the World?

Comment: Hi, Moonboots.

Yeah, the world is the default gray. I played around with it and changed it to FFFFFF(White) still the strength is at default. And now it is white.

Comment: I also tried setting the world strength to 0 and now it is dark.

Comment: don't you want to use an HDRI image? It would make it more natural

Comment: I did and it game me the same results. The material is also noisy.

Comment: noisy? i thought your problem is that the reflection was black, if you use an HDRI image it should reflect the image, maybe pack your image and share your file?

Comment: Do you have denoise on in your render settings?